# How to find a tab in Firefox, that runs certain plugin right now?

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs, container, browser-plugin

If the Plugin Container running, then how to determine, which tabs need it, and, if possible, which plugins the tabs utilise?

Answer (score 1):

Looking for the Plugin symbol near the URL will let you know which tabs are running a plugin. [image: firefox plugin symbol]

Also, Process explorer can make it clear sometimes which plugin a container is running. here is an image showing flash player as a child of a plugin container.

[image: process explorer]

The permission screen of Tools > "Page Info" can also provide hints about which plugins that page may be using. Look for the "Allow" option. it means you said "always run" in the past for a certain plugin on that page.

Comment: It's a good advice, but I have dozens of tabs in every of dozen tab groups, and I want a method that points directly to needed tab(s), for example, by page title (it would be the best). And also it would be good to know, which plugins utilised by which tabs.

Comment: It would appear that Firefox may not natively have this feature. You could request that firefox add this.  If this feature did exist it would probably be one of the sub-pages of about:about, such as about:performance.